# How to change the brightness for all three channels of the image?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to change the brightness of an image by coverting it from BGR to LAB and changing the L parameter to L+brightness. It works to change the brightness but the output image is blue , why?

```
void MainWindow::BrightnessSlider(cv::Mat image)
{


    cv::Mat image2;
    cv::cvtColor(image,image2,cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);

    for (int i=0; i < image2.rows; i++)
   {
        for (int j=0; j < image2.cols; j++)

        {
            image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(image2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] + brightness);
             
        }
    }
    cv::cvtColor(image2,image2,cv::COLOR_Lab2BGR);
    QImage imageupdate= QImage((const unsigned char*)(image2.data), image2.cols,image2.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);

    int w = ui->label->width();
    int h =ui-> label->height();
   ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageupdate.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio)));


}
```

Comment: What is the brightness value inside the code ? How does `image2` look like just after converting lab to bgr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that 3-channel color images in OpenCV use **BGR** memory layout, while in Qt they use **RGB** memory layout. That's why your image shown in QLabel looks "blue".

To fix the memory layout problem, you should change `cv::COLOR_Lab2BGR` to `cv::COLOR_Lab2RGB` in the second `cv::cvtColor()`:

```cpp
cv::cvtColor(image2, image2, cv::COLOR_Lab2RGB);
```

**Or** append `.rgbSwapped()` to `imageupdate` (note that `imageupdate` will not share memory block with `image2`):

```cpp
QImage imageupdate = QImage((const unsigned char*)(image2.data),
     image2.cols, image2.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
```

BTW, you can just use `Mat::operator+(const Scalar&)` to change the value for all pixels, the color conversion and for-loops are unnecessary:

```cpp
cv::Mat image2 = image + cv::Scalar::all(brightness);
// convert BGR to RGB if you don't want to allocate additional memory
// for imageupdate with QImage::rgbSwapped():
cv::cvtColor(image2, image2, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
```